# Should a JQuery plugin be responsible for creating new HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am not quite sure what the best (or most common practice) is when needing HTML elements for your JQuery plugin to work. For example (although contrived), if you required a spinner (ticker) plugin where you would have text box containing a number and to the left of the box a up and down arrow. When the up arrow is clicked the value is incremented and the value is decremented when the down arrow is clicked.

I see some JQuery plugins, especially the JQuery UI widgets, that expect you to supply all the html and to give them special classes.

In the case of the spinner would you just expect the input tag and then in the JQuery plugin generate the HTML to render the up and down buttons?

Perhaps a better example is something like creating a paging data grid. Would the paging buttons (First, Last, Previous, Next, Page 1, Page 2...) be generated by the plugin or should the user of the plugin be expected to create HTML with special classes.

Comment: I know some plugins which create dynamic html (mostly sliders). Its upto you. Letting user decide the html is more flexible though. He can decide the position and the element. jquery ui doest not need special classes.

Comment: @Jashwant I guess I more meant a snippet of html with a specific structure. For example the tab plugin wants <div><ul><li>..</li><div id=tab1></div></div>. I suppose this is just a decent way to let the user specify what they want. I guess passing all that in as arguments to the plugin would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `jqGrid`. It generates a lot of HTML, but it leaves the `<table>` and `pager` elements up to you. It then obviously appends to these elements. But it also creates siblings and containers for these elements as well.

For example,

```
<!-- index.html -->
<table id="mygrid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>

// main.js
$('#mygrid').jqGrid({pager: '#pager', ...});
```

jqGrid not only appends to #mygrid and #pager, but also creates new siblings and containers.

```
<div id="gbox_mygrid">
   <div class="ui-jqgrid-view">
      <table id="mygrid"><!-- rows --></table>
   </div>
   <div id="#pager"><!-- stuff --> <?div>
</div>
```

So you see that jqGrid does what it has to do, to work well. I think it depends on the needs of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I find myself redoing the same bits of code around tables. It always has a filter and some paging buttons etc. So I was hoping to turn it into a component so I could just easily reuse that code.

Comment: Basic templating will help generating html in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would expect the developer to supply only the container element along with any essential inner elements (think images in a slider). I would expect the plugin to generate any controls like buttons, pagination, etc.

Requiring the developer to supply a container element gives them complete control over how, when, and where your plugin appears on *their* page, as if it was just another div. Requiring them to also supply any necessary content isn't always necessary, as this could just as easily be a config item.

The main upside I see to having the user supply HTML comes when dealing with clients that don't support/allow JavaScript (think old browsers, spiders, etc). At least they'll see *something* related to what your plugin was meant to display, rather than just an ugly blank space. In the slider example, if done properly, the plugin can gracefully degrade to a static image in the case of lacking JavaScript support.

All intricacies such as controls and status displays should *always* be generated by the plugin. Why? User-friendliness is the first thing that comes to mind. People use jQuery plugins because they want a fast, relatively pain-free solution to a problem. Additionally, many users of jQuery plugins are not web developers, but instead are often just administrators of blogs and such.

By eliminating the need for the users of your plugin to have to create elements that they really have no control over, you also eliminate a lot of headaches caused by typos, misunderstandings, and lack of RTFMing.

Hopefully my opinions and insights have been helpful.